# center div to screen but have another div in the same line

Tags: html, css, layout

I need to have a div which content is always centered relative to the screen, but i also have other div to the left of the want i want to center. If I just center the content of the "center" div, it will center relatively to its div width, not the screens.

[Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/ufazek/2/edit) of what I tried

and what I want si something like this...

```
|                              true  center                              |
|left div|                      centered D                               |
|longer left div|               centered D                               |
|another even longer left div|  centered D                               |
```

Asume "true center" is the center of the screen, that one is easy.

But I want that all "centered D" divs to be centered to screen to, but they have divs to their left (which I put there using floats), which makes them to shift right.

Obviously, in my attempt ([see example](http://jsbin.com/ufazek/2/edit)), the divs are not going to be centered to the screen, but to their divs width, which is expected, but not what I need.

what do I need to center the divs to the screen, no matter if they have other divs in the same line?

I suspect i am doing it wrong and it maybe will be trivial, but I am kind of new with css layouts.

Thanks

Comment: How would this work?  Will "centered D" be behind the others?  will it's width be dependent on the left side?

Comment: both left and center divs will have buttons, with different texts (hence the variable width), but i need the center ones to always be centered, regarding their (and left div's) width. And I don't understand what do you mean by "behind", I expect they wont overlap, left divs shouldn't be be width enough to overlap with center divs, but it is good to consider it! what if screens width is small enough... I guess then, center should be pushed to the right, as to have both always visible.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your `.left` class absolutely positioned, those divs won't offset the centered text.

```
.left{
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: excelent! that is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is put the `.left` divs *inside* the center divs. Then I would get rid of the `float:left` and just do an absolute position. You can do just the absolute positioning without moving the `.left` divs around, but you will run into issues with different browsers rendering the page differently because you don't define the `top` and `left` in the CSS. By putting the `.left` divs inside the center divs you can add the top and left CSS and prevent browsers from rendering different things:

```
.center {
    //You need to add relative position for the absolute to align properly
    position:relative;
}
.left {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

...and your HTML will look like:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="left">left-aligned content</div>
    centered content
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this too. EDIT: just to clarify to others, you still need the text-align:center; in the .center class.

Comment: @DiegoDD Yes, that's correct. The above code should be added to the existing code; it is not meant to replace it. With the exception of removing the `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a div that has 200px width and you want it to be centered.
Try this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="centered">
    Content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#centered{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
```

margin-left is -100px because to center a div the calculation is -width/2